# Guess the Beatles songs from the initials number 1

Tags: music

Guess which beatles song this is as I give you the initials to the first few lyrics.
I O H A G
O S I S
S O H M
S S M H R
I I G
N W

Comment: I've said this in comments on another of your puzzles but I will say it here too in case you are only looking at the most recent ones: Please (1) do not post lots of puzzles within a short time period and (2) do not ask people for upvotes. No more than one a day would be reasonable, and for "cookie-cutter" puzzles like this that are basically all the same, even that is too many. And votes are meant to reflect how well puzzles were received, not how much the poster asked for upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is

> Norwegian Wood, I think.

Comment: I didn't know if you'd get that one

Comment: @William Heh, I've listened to the Beatles a lot...

Comment: I think the last line gives it a bit away ;p Great answer Carmeister, +1

Comment: I'm gonna do something called guess who. Hope you like it